# Use data from pandas to do numpy loops

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a big dataframe with trading data, and I am trying to group the data in small clusters. I have a column called Ticks, with either 1,-1 or 0. I want to do a conditional statement like "if tick is 1 or -1, count 1, if it is 0 don't add anything but still keep that trade in memory. Once we reach 1000 (so 1000 occurences with either 1 or -1, and all the lines with "0" in between), create a new array and continue this operation.

I read about numpy and how it is much faster than traditional python loops, but I'm not sure how to do this without loops. I read quite a few similar stackoverflow issues and explanations about vectorization etc... But I have to admit I did not really understand them, maybe because my math level is too low or I did not understand the code used in the example. But I couldn't find an example with data from pandas converted to numpy. [example of my dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJbfc.png)

Comment: see how to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to accomplish that is using the `cumsum` remainder of the target sum value, so every sum up to 1000 will mark a new array to be splited. The downside of this solution is that you still have to iterate over the variable length arrays.

Random choice array used as input:

```
[ 1 -1  0 -1 -1  0 -1 -1 -1  0  0 -1  0  0 -1  1  0 -1  1  1  0 -1  0  0
  1 -1  0  1  1 -1  1  0 -1  0 -1 -1  1  1  1 -1 -1  1 -1  0 -1 -1  1 -1
  1  1 -1  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0 -1  0  0  1  1  1 -1  1  1  0  1  1  1
  0 -1  0  0  0  1 -1  1 -1  1  1  1  0  0 -1  1  0 -1  1  0  1  0 -1 -1
  0  0  0  1]
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

TARGET_SUM = 5  # change to 1000 here

pds = pd.Series(np.random.choice([-1, 0, 1], size=100))
x = (pds!=0).cumsum()
ix = x.loc[(x % TARGET_SUM == 0) & (x > 0)].drop_duplicates().index

ix += 1
ix = ix.insert(0, 0)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for idx in range(len(ix)-1):
    new_arr = pds[ix[idx]:ix[idx + 1]].to_list()
    df = df.append([[new_arr, len(new_arr), np.sum(np.abs(new_arr))]], ignore_index=True)

df.columns=["NEW_ARRAY","LEN(NEW_ARRAY)","SUM(ABS(NEW_ARRAY))"]
print(df)
r = len(pds)- df.iloc[:,1].sum()
print("Unused values from original df: {} - {} = {}".format(len(pds), df.iloc[:,1].sum(), r))
```

Output from **df**

```
                         NEW_ARRAY  LEN(NEW_ARRAY)  SUM(ABS(NEW_ARRAY))
0         [1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, -1]               7                    5
1   [-1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1]               9                    5
2     [0, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1]               9                    5
3              [-1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1]               6                    5
4          [0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 1]               7                    5
5                [1, -1, -1, 1, -1]               5                    5
6             [0, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1]               6                    5
7               [1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1]               6                    5
8   [1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]              10                    5
9               [-1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]               6                    5
10    [1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 1]               9                    5
11          [-1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, -1]               7                    5
12       [1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 0, -1]               8                    5

Unused values from original df: 100 - 95 = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without an explicit for loop, but I'm not sure if this uses loops under the hood, sry :D

```
x = pd.Series([0,1,-1,0,1,1,1,-1,0,1,1,-1]) # or x = df['Tick']
x = (x!=0).cumsum()
ix = x.loc[x==5].index[0] # I put 5 to work on this example, but you can set to 1000
```

And `ix`  will be the index corresponding to the occurrence of the first time you reached 1000 values different from zero.